# Chrome clean up sessionStorage after some time

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, session-storage

After the app starts up I am setting some variables into the `sessionStorage`, but after some time `sessionStorage` is cleaned up.
Tested on 3 different environments.
Tested on 3 different app and static servers.
Tested on Windows and MacOS.
Tested in Chrome, Mozilla, Safari, Chromium, and Edge (Reproduced only in Chrome).

For example one of the Chrome versions where the issue is reproducible:
Version 114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) (arm64)

Here is the code to reproduce:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<script>

  sessionStorage.setItem('TEST', 'TEST value')
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('100ms', sessionStorage.getItem('TEST')) }, 100)
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('200ms', sessionStorage.getItem('TEST')) }, 200)
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('300ms', sessionStorage.getItem('TEST')) }, 300)
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('500ms', sessionStorage.getItem('TEST')) }, 500)
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('1000ms', sessionStorage.getItem('TEST')) }, 1000)
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('2000ms', sessionStorage.getItem('TEST')) }, 2000)
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('3000ms', sessionStorage.getItem('TEST')) }, 3000)

</script>

<body>
<h1>Welcome to My Website</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But the steps to reproduce are a little bit tricky. It's reproducible only on some app servers or static servers. For example [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

1. Open the incognito Chrome window.
2. Open a new tab
3. Insert the URL of the server
4. Open the dev-tool and check logs (You need to repeat step 2-4 up to 5-10 times to catch the issue)

Note: Don't open dev-tool before opening the URL. In this case, it won't be reproduced.

[image: Logs of issue]

I can't figure out how this issue can exist. It is a bug in so fundamental functionality of the browser. For example, in my case, it brakes a big commercial app.

Question: Did somebody face it? Do you have some workaround? Any information would be helpful. I am wondering why I can't find any open issues or questions about this case.

Comment: Don't some servers have timed cache? I'm front-end so I'm not completely sure if that's an actual factor.

Comment: What is the question? your [sessionStorage is cleaned some time after you leave the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). localStorage is not

Comment: @mplungjan Added the question. Did somebody face it? Do you have some workaround?

Comment: @zer00ne I don't think that cache plays some role here. For me, it looks like some chrome optimization that in this particular case make an issue. But I can't be sure. Thx for the suggestion.

Comment: I have never seen this, then again I never use sessionStorage.

Comment: @mplungjan Regarding your link. Thx. The issue is happening not when I leave a page. It's happening for example after 300-500ms after I enter the page.
Start page - set some variable into sessionStorage - after 500ms it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

> The NPMJS package http-server has the cache time of 3600 seconds meaning an hour and in some certain scenarios like if there is a latency problem, when reloading and buffering the data that the live server is rendering, the session Storage data that is stored within the live server's tab in the browser could be lost from a new caching cycle occurring or just in general lost / overlooked / ignored.

What you could do is that you store the sessionStorage in a variable by stating a variable when setting the item like so, `let storage_one = sessionStorage.setItem('TEST', 'TEST_VALUE');`.

This might help by reminding the live server to keep the sessionStorage and not to be ignored or you can simply create a variable that has the value of the sessionStorage by grabbing its value which seems like the better option because if the sessionStorage is lost then you can't do anything with a variable just having the value of it being set but with the this option, you can easily just call the variable's value and you're covered. It will also allow for easier code,
`let storage_one = sessionStorage.getItem('TEST', 'TEST_VALUE');`

I hope this helps :)

**P.S. - Stackoverflow won't you allow to run this code but I assure you this works.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<script>

  sessionStorage.setItem('TEST', 'TEST value');
  let teststorageval = sessionStorage.getItem('TEST');
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('100ms',teststorageval); }, 100);
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('200ms', teststorageval); }, 200);
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('300ms', teststorageval); }, 300);
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('500ms', teststorageval); }, 500);
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('1000ms', teststorageval); }, 1000);
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('2000ms', teststorageval); }, 2000);
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('3000ms', teststorageval); }, 3000);

</script>

<body>
<h1>Welcome to My Website</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for so a detailed answer. Unfortunately, your code solution is not helping. This is small reproduction. In the real app, I read and write these properties from different isolated parts of the app at different moments of time. So I cant just get that property and keep it on the variable. I need to work with storage dynamically. I don't think that issue is in the server. I tested with 3 different servers and many browsers. Issue reproducible only in the Chrome.

Comment: Have you made sure your version of Chrome is up-to-date?

Comment: Yes. I have added the Chrome version to the description. And it was reproduced in a couple of other environments also.